# MySQL query with many AND OR. Need to understand how (in what order) data is filtered

Tags: mysql

Aim is to understand how `AND` `OR` works filtering data from multiple columns.

Here is sample of query

```
SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE 
EntryId > 10 
AND EntryId != 23
AND EntryId NOT LIKE %24%
AND 
RecordDay = 17 OR RecordDay = 16
```

With this query I want

1) At first select all results where value in `EntryId` is more than 10

2) Then exclude results where value in `EntryId` is 23

3) Then exclude results where value value in `EntryId` contains 24 (with `AND EntryId NOT LIKE %24%` I mean: show me results, where `EntryId` does not contain 24)

4) Then from results above show only results where `RecordDay` is equal to 17 and also show results where `RecordDay` is equal to 16 (with `RecordDay = 17 OR RecordDay = 16` I mean: show me results (rows) where `RecordDay` is equal to 17 or `RecordDay` is equal to 16)

But in output see result where `EntryId` is 24 (contrary to `EntryId NOT LIKE %24%`).

Do I need to group `AND` `OR` regarding each MySQL Column?

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE 
(EntryId > 10 
AND EntryId != 23
AND EntryId NOT LIKE %24%)
AND 
(RecordDay = 17 OR RecordDay = 16)
```

From advises made some conclusions.

If want to filter results to see following results DD/MM: 01/04, 01/03, 06/04, 06/03
is the code correct?

```
(RecordDay = 01 OR RecordDay = 06)
AND (RecordMonth = 04 OR RecordMonth = 03)
```

Think about some possibilities and made conclusion that better not to use `OR` at all. Because I can not know which order user would want.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal 
WHERE 
(EntryId LIKE '%10%' OR EntryId LIKE '%23%') 
AND
EntryId NOT LIKE '%4%'
AND 
(RecordDay = 17 OR RecordDay = 16") ;
```

//EntryId contains 10 and 23, but does not contain 4 and RecordDay is 17 or 16 (for example EntryId/RecordDay 100/17, 231/17, 1023/16

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal 
WHERE EntryId LIKE '%10%' 
OR 
(EntryId LIKE '%23%' AND EntryId NOT LIKE '%4%')
AND
(RecordDay = 17 OR RecordDay = 16") ;
```

//EntryId/RecordDay 104/17 because contains 10 OR (contains 23 and does not contain 4) 104/17 contains 10 and there is no requirement that it must not contain 4

`AND` `OR` in the two queries are the same. But position of `()` is different. So output would be different?

Now made conclusion if want query with `OR` better to create possibility in input field (for filter) to write multiple values for filter. For example if I want to see results, where months are April, May, June, in input field to write 04, 05, 06.

Please, correct me if my conclusions are wrong

Comment: Group the conditions with parenthesis... `(x !=1 AND x !=2) OR (x=3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, AND and OR fragments should *always* be wrapped in parenthesis when both are being used or the result can easily be the one you don't expect.  It will also make life simpler for anyone else reading your query.  In your case, one set of parenthesis would suffice:

```
SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal 
WHERE EntryId > 10 
  AND EntryId != 23
  AND EntryId NOT LIKE '%24%'
  AND (RecordDay = 17 OR RecordDay = 16)
```

For readability, it is common to wrap each fragment independently:

```
SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal 
WHERE (EntryId > 10)
  AND (EntryId != 23)
  AND (EntryId NOT LIKE '%24%')
  AND (RecordDay = 17 OR RecordDay = 16)
```